# issue installing lxml on python3.5 on windows

Tags: python-3.5

I am trying to install lxml from lxml-3.6.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl  and then for installing I am giving command "pip install lxml-3.6.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl" on cmd and am getting error:
lxml-3.6.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not supported wheel on this platform.
how can I install the lxml?